# Using i18next in Node.js models

Tags: node.js, mongoose, i18next

I want to use [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) in a Node.js + Mongoose + MongoDB based Web API application to return localized error messages. Here's how I initialize i18next in `app.js`:

```
const i18next = require("i18next");
const i18nextBackend = require("i18next-fs-backend");
const i18nextMiddleware = require("i18next-http-middleware");
const i18nConfig = require("./config/i18nConfig.json");
i18next.use(i18nextBackend).init(i18nConfig, (err, t) => {});
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next, {}));
```

where `./config/i18nConfig.json` is an `i18next` configuration file as its name suggests.

After this, I can import `i18next` and use its `t()` method to translate error messages in *controllers* as follows:

```
const i18next = require("i18next");
...
const error = new HttpError(i18next.t("messages.user.emailMissing"), 422);
return next(error);
```

where `HttpError` is an Error plus a HTTP error code and `messages.user.emailMissing` is a key to a localized string. Translation works perfectly here.

I want to use `i18next` in *models* as well, to return localized validation error messages. Here is such a model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, i18next.t("messages.user.emailMissing")],
    validate: [validator.isEmail, i18next.t("messages.user.emailInvalid")],
  },
  ...
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

However, I don't know how to reference i18next in a model. When I try to simply import it like in a controller, I'll get `undefined`. When I initialize it just like in app.js I'll get the key `messages.user.emailMissing` instead of the translation.

So far, I found no examples that would show me a way. Any ideas, pointers etc. are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class instance

```
// i18n.js

const i18next = require("i18next");
const Backend = require("i18next-node-fs-backend");
const i18nextMiddleware = require("i18next-http-middleware");

class I18nManager {
  t;
  init = ({ app } = {}) => {
    i18next
      .use(Backend)
      .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
      .init({
        backend: {
          loadPath: "locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json",
        },
        fallbackLng: "en",
        preload: ["en", "es"],
      })
      .then((_t) => (this.t = _t));

    if (app) app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));
  };
}

const i18n = new I18nManager();

module.exports = {
  i18n,
  t: (...args) => i18n.t(...args),
};
```

Then initialize the i18next instance in the app.js

```
//app.js

const app = require("express")();
const { i18n } = require("./i18n");

i18n.init({ app });
```

And then import the translate function into your model

```
// model.js

const { t } = require("./i18n");

t("mykey", { lng: "es" })
```